# Meteor - redirect several connected clients from array?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an array of clients with their _id's from mongo, I wanted to know how can I route all of them (at once) to a page using router?

example: 3 users are landing on a page named "game", when there are 3 people I have an array which saves their userID, all the users with their ID's saved in the array should be routed to another page (for examle: "page2"). I understand that this should be done from server side perspective but im having a hard time to figure this one out.

```
//client
Template.GameLayout.onRendered(function () {
var ses = Session.get("loggedIn");
Meteor.call('userCounter', ses, function(error, fullArray){

if(error && error.error === "noArray"){
  console.log(error);
  console.log("I have error");
} else {
  if(fullArray){
  var usersArray = fullArray[1];
  var randomGen = fullArray[0];

  console.log(randomGen);
}
}
})




//server
 userCounter: function(sessions){


  usersArray.push(sessions);

  var usersConnected = usersArray.length;

  if(!usersConnected){
    throw new Meteor.Error("noArray");
    console.log("oops heres the problem");
  } else {

  if(usersConnected > 2){


    var randomGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999) + 1;
    var fullArray = [randomGen, usersArray];
    console.log(fullArray);
    return fullArray;
    usersArray =[];
  }
}

  }
```

Comment: A little more clarity would help. Why do you want to redirect the users? And on what basis do you want to do that? Where do you want to initiate the redirection (server-side or client-side) ?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would just do this in a `Tracker.autorun()` on the client-side, ex:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  if ( ... condition that you want to re-route on ... ){
    Router.go('page2');
  }
});
```

Your array would have to be published in a collection of some kind, say *active games* so that the client could do its logic and route accordingly.